# How is the Heisenberg Uncertainty calculated value added to a measurement error bar?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, metrology

It is not clear to me if the calculated HU for a specific experiment is added to the measured value  Gaussian curve together with the statistical errors (i.e. added to the total error bar) of this measurement and in which way?

I know that statistical errors like systemic errors are chaotic deterministic in nature whereas HU is probabilistic.

Can you give me the method (using maybe an example) by which the HU is integrated to the total calculated error bar for a measurement in the field of Quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one adds uncertainties from the uncertainty principle as errors to measurements. For one, that wouldn't make a lot of sense because measurements don't always know what actual quantum state they're dealing with prior to measurement and hence couldn't even calculate that uncertainty if they wanted to, but more importantly: Because that's not what "uncertainty" means. Uncertainty is *not* an "error" on any specific measurement.

Uncertainty of a random variable $x$ is its *standard deviation* $\sigma_x = \sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle - \langle x\rangle^2}$. Quantum mechanics rests on the idea that the result of measuring an observable $A$ on a certain state $\lvert \psi\rangle$ is effectively a random variable, with $\langle A\rangle = \langle \psi\vert A\vert \psi \rangle$ the expectation value of that variable.

Now, statistics tells us by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) that the average of our results after $N$ measurements will tend towards the expectation value as $N$ becomes larger, just as the [sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation) of our results will tend towards the theoretical standard deviation $\sigma_A$.

In more "physics-like" language, the statistical error of our measurements converges towards the uncertainty from the uncertainty principle as we increase the number of measurements. Other than that, the theoretical value does not have anything to do with the *actual errors* we should use for our experimental sample.

Comment: So if you measure for example the charge of the electron $-e$ the uncertainty in the measurement indicated by the brackets (...) at the end of the number does not include the HU value?

Comment: @Markoul11 Heisenberg uncertainty deals with putting limits on conjoint measurements. There is no meaningful way in which you can talk about the Heisenberg uncertainty on the measurement of a single observable. The quantum mechanical uncertainty in the measurement of a single observable depends simply on the state that you are measuring and you can reduce it arbitrarily by appropriately preparing the state. The point of the Heisenberg limit is that you can't do this preparation of state to simultaneously and arbitrarily reduce the uncertainties in the measurement of two different observables.

Comment: As for the measurement of electric charge, we live in superselection sectors of electric charge, i.e., you can never create states that are superpositions of different electric charges. This means that there is no quantum mechanical uncertainty in the measurement of electric charge because all states are ensured to be eigenstates of electric charge.

Comment: @Markoul11 Yes, my explanation of what uncertainty means is fully general and applies to *all* observables. The experimental errors include the *sample standard deviation* as statistical error if it is meaningful to do so, never the theoretical uncertainty. Note that for charge the theoretical uncertainty is zero (electrons have a definite charge) to begin with, so asking whether it is included or not is even less meaningful than in the general case.